# How to create an object in Typescript avoiding to initialize GET properties?

Tags: typescript

if a declare a class

```
class MyClass {
   a: number;
   get b(): number { return this.a * 2 };
}
```

I'm wondering why when I initialize an object of type "MyClass" the prop "b" is required even if it's just readonly (get) property

example code:

```
var myObject: MyClass = { a: 10 };
```

so this will throw a typescript error:

**Property 'b' is missing in type '{ a: number; }' but required in type 'MyClass'.**

Comment: Readonly doesn’t affect the fact that it needs to show up in the object as constrained by the interface. There’s noticeable diff, `obj.hasOwnProperty` test gives diff result.

Comment: When you declare a variable of type `MyClass`, normal way to initialize it is using `var myObject: MyClass = new MyClass()`. Care to explain why you opt not to?

Comment: I cannot use the new MyClass() constructor, i need to declare my object as above

Comment: If you can't use `new MyClass()` then your `class` is not being used at all and you should get rid of it; it is only confusing you.  The *type* named `MyClass` is essentially an interface like `{a: number; readonly b: number}`.  It does *not* mean "something definitely created by the `MyClass` constructor".  Keep in mind that TypeScript compiles to JavaScript, mostly by removing type annotations, so this becomes something like `class MyClass { ... }` and then `var myObject = { a: 10 }`.  You can't expect `myObject` to have a `b` property because you didn't give it one.

Comment: "I cannot use the new `MyClass()` constructor, i need to declare my object as above".  Why?  We need a use case if you want a suggestion for what to do.  If you just want to know why the above code doesn't work (aside from the typo where you mention bare `a` instead of `this.a`) then I can expand the above comments into an answer, but I don't know that will actually help whatever underlying issue you're facing.

Comment: I have a file that contains the whole object and for me is better to visualize it with syntax inside my question. IN THAT FILE, imagine this file like a json that store my object, i would prefere to don't use the constructor, just to display all the properties belonging to that class. So there is any way to declare a typed object and avoid the get properties?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow exactly but you either need to use the constructor, supply the `b` property, or define `myObject` to be of type `Omit<MyClass, "b">` and not `MyClass`.  Does that last suggestion work for you?  If so I can make it an answer.  Note that there's no way for the compiler to distinguish a `get`-property-without-a-`set` from a `readonly` property.  If you want to omit all `readonly` properties from a type that's possible:

Comment: Like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgZgUQI4FcCGAbAzgHgBoA0UAmkQIIC8hUAQhQHYQBuEATgHxQUBQUUAFDgAq7fgEounIVAgAPYBHoATLFDxQA-FACMUAFxQATBLkLlWXgOGiJFKTPmKVJTTv1GJWsu5oBubtygkFAA6qwAlsBoAEYYEADSECC4IlxQAN6WANoAClDh9FAA1kkA9nBQQgC6ALQaBvDI6Ng46VBZAIr5hTlVBkK5VVAAvkRtNawQaEql9Bgg7V0FUL39gyNEOezcw1klIOWVVf6B4NA54QDGRWGRMXHWaRfXwkS3UbEJSSns7CeXGDQWFUAFkQABhQHAjKWKBoAz0FAAW2ibDS2n8fCgAHMIMAoNFxAjkajWBkoJNgChWIVgAALcJYAB0aCgACojCN-MMAkw0GSkSAAPLRABWEEuwAMzxuEQ+DzBkKBWE4FHJ8J0AAYudwgA).  Let me know if that meets your needs and I'll write it up if so.

Comment: thanks for your help  jcalz, it was very good

Answer (score 0):

You can't create class like object, you need to call constructor with `new`

```js
class MyClass {
   get b(): number { return this.a * 2 };
   constructor(public a: number) { }
}

var myObject: MyClass = new MyClass(10);
```

and now you have access to `a` and `b` property

```js
console.log(myObject.a, myObject.b);
```

**UPDATE**

also you can do something like this, when you are creating class from json/interface

```js
interface IMyInterface {
  a: number
}

class MyClass implements IMyInterface {
  a: number;
  get b(): number { return this.a * 2 };
  constructor(json: IMyInterface) {
    this.a = json.a;
  }
}

const myObject = new MyClass({a: 10});
```

or if you want to auto initialize all members from interface to class

```js
constructor(json: IMyInterface) {
  Object.keys(json).forEach(key => {
    this[key] = json[key];
  });
}
```

Comment: I just added more examples, maybe it's gonna fit your needs